# Setting Event.target for using events in unit testing

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, events, flexunit

I want to override flash.display.Loader and to dispatch my own Event with a my own target.content

How can i override Event.target?
"Property is read only"

Or use some other way to unit test the loading sequence

tnx
Hed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target is always set to the object that dispatches the event.  The proper way to unit test loading *sequence* is to mock the loaders - this unit test should test the logic used for loading sequentially, not the file system or network connection.

Wrap your loader into a custom class implementing a custom loader interface that extends IEventDispatcher.  Use that interface to create a mock loader, and dispatch the event from the mock object.

Comment: I did mock the Loader + did dispatch the event from the Loader - 
but didn't see it set as a target
I'll check again
(If it is being set that's good enough for my tests)

Answer (score 0):

You can't override target property. Though you can trick flash with special custom extended event but that will get ugly very soon.

What you need to do is to create a mock loader which contains a Loader instance, catches its event and dispatches a new one.